# How to intercept responses with Ktor?

Tags: ktor

I used to intercept with OkHttp this way:

```
override fun intercept(chain: Chain): Response {
        var response: Response = chain.proceed(request.newBuilder().build())
        if (response.code == 401) {
            performSilentLogin()
        }
}
```

How to do the same thing with Ktor?

edit:

I've created a custom Auth plugin following the [documentation](https://ktor.io/docs/client-custom-plugins.html).

This is my code:

```
val AuthPlugin = createClientPlugin("AuthPlugin", ::AuthPluginConfig) {
    val contentType:ContentType = pluginConfig.contentType

    on(Send) { request ->
        val originalCall = proceed(request)
        originalCall.response.run {
            if (status == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) {
                val username = credentialsManager.getString("username", "")
                val password = credentialsManager.getString("password", "")
                val requestBody = LoginRequest(username, password)
                request.contentType(contentType)
                request.setBody(requestBody)

                proceed(request)
            } else {
                originalCall
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I get an exception:

> exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No request transformation
> found: LoginRequest(username= "the username", password="the password")

Comment: To do it, you can write a plugin. You can find more information in the documentation (https://ktor.io/docs/client-custom-plugins.html).

Comment: @AlekseiTirman I've edited my question.

Comment: Please describe what problem you are trying to solve with the plugin.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman When I get 401 status code I want to make a silent login, so I login with the credentials saved in storage.

Comment: I suggest using the standard `Auth` (https://ktor.io/docs/auth.html) plugin and only then try a solution built with a custom plugin.